# is user-extension must for selenium RC?

Tags: selenium-rc, user-extensions.js

I have created a project in Eclipse for Selenium automation using testNG framework. I have never used any user extension file in the past, but I heard that we need to use an user extension file. As since I am unsure of the proper use of this file I have never used it and my project runs smoothly. The question now arises is that later on will I have any issues because of not using an user-extension file? Please give me some ideas on the user extension file and let me know whether its mandatory to use in selenium RC project.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `user-extensions.js` file is not required.  But you may indeed need to use it, if your existing tests depend on an extension that is in it.  Obviously, at that point you need to use the version of the file that the test author used.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your question is but I think the answer is No anyway, you do not need to have any "user extension files" in order to use selenium API in any JAVA testing environment. You just call API from your testNG or other testing frameworks. see http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/java/